# Event handlers only work when event is passed as an argument - why?

Tags: javascript, list, function, event-handling, dom-events

I want to build a function to toggle/untoggle all items of a list (`populateList()` is a separate function to write the actual html):

```
function toggleAll(event, check) {
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (check === "check") {
      item.done = true;
    } else {
      item.done = false;
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
  populateList(items, itemsList);
}
```

When clicking on the according buttons (`checkAll`/`uncheckAll`) the function should be fired:

```
const checkAll = document.querySelector(".check");
const uncheckAll = document.querySelector(".uncheck");

checkAll.addEventListener("click", toggleAll("check"));
uncheckAll.addEventListener("click", toggleAll("uncheck"));
```

Apparently this does not work. For some reasons the function `toggleAll` is run only once at page load, the buttons do not react. I tried to pass the event itself with the following code:

```
checkAll.addEventListener("click", (event) => toggleAll(event, "check"));
uncheckAll.addEventListener("click", (event) => toggleAll(event, "uncheck"));
```

This works just fine! I have no clue why.
Could somebody please enlighten me on this? What am I overlooking here?

Comment: `checkAll.addEventListener("click", toggleAll("check"));` **calls** `toggleAll("check")` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar()` and passes its return value to `foo`. `checkAll.addEventListener("click", (event) => toggleAll(event, "check"));` creates an arrow function (`(event) => toggleAll(event, "check")`) that will call `toggleAll` when it's called.

Comment: thanks for the swift comment. I still dont get why it does not work with only checkAll.addEventListener("click", toggleAll("check"));

Comment: You need to pass a function into `addEventListener` as its second argument. `checkAll.addEventListener("click", toggleAll("check"));` doesn't do that. Instead, again, it **calls** `toggleAll("check")` and passes its return value into `addEventListener`. So instead of hooking up a handler to be called later when the event occurs, you've **called** the handler right away (and only passed it one argument, where it expects two).

Comment: thanks for clarification! I thought  `toggleAll("check")` is a function. btw. also when I defined the function with one argument `function toggleAll(check)` it did not work either...

Comment: No, `toggleAll("check")` is a function **call**. `toggleAll` is a function.

Comment: After re-reading it 2 weeks later, I fully understand now. Makes total sense - many thanks @T.J.Crowder